# Variable not initialized in Java

Tags: java

Anybody can tell me the problem? I initialized the variable *netClass1* but still giving me the error.
I tried `netClass1 = '';` but still giving me an error.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MP3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);

    String pc1 = "";
    char netClass1;

    // PC1
    System.out.print("Enter IP: ");
    pc1 = get.nextLine().trim();

    String[] ip1 = pc1.split("\\.");
    
    int pc1Octet1 = Integer.parseInt(ip1[0]);

    if (pc1Octet1 >= 0 || pc1Octet1 <= 127) {
        netClass1 = 'A';
    }

    System.out.println("Class: " + netClass1);

}// end main
}// end class
```

[image: output]

Comment: char's are actual characters, you can't have a character that is nothing............ 
you could do `netClass1 = ' ';` because a space is a character

Comment: @RobOhRob that made sense and new to me. thanks. Ill take note of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only initialize the variable `netClass1` in the if block. But if your program doesn't enter that block, the variable will not be initialized, that's why you get the error.

Comment: ow thanks. So I need to have an else block for fallback. It worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like what is said, netClass1may not be initialized, I know you did

```
netClass1 = '';
```

But a char can not be empty, so...

```
netClass1 = '0';
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary for you to initialize a variable during declaration. But you must assign any value.

Yeah, you assign 'A' but unfortunately some times this block may not be exected.

So, it may be uninitialized.

But java, during compile time if java find any variable uninitialized if throw exception.

Moreover, netClass1 = '' it is wrong way to initialize a char. It will be netClass1 = 'A'